# Agora UI video call quality with expo

Tags: expo, agora.io, videocall, videoquality, expo-dev-client

I am working with expo dev-client and I am trying to build an app that has video calling as one of its functions. I am currently using agoraUI for that purpose. I am currently using agora's most basic services. When I test the video call with a device and a simulator the video quality is not great, there is at least 1 second delay on video, and the sound does not match video. This function is very important for my app, is this happening because of the simulator or is it an effect of using agoraUI?